# java Apache L4J - logging to file known only during the runtime

Tags: java, log4j

Is there a simple way to achieve what I described in the topic?

I know that normally, l4j.properties contains information about the file, where we store informations. The catch is that will have the file during the runtime, so I need to set file in some kind of dynamic way and append new logs to it?

Any ideas?

Comment: didn't get your question

Comment: I want to use Apache Log4J to log some information to the file. Normally U just set the file in the l4j.properties, but I won't know the filename before the runtime. That's why I cannot set it properties file and I am looking for solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
    String logFile = ...// log4j.xml absolute path
    DOMConfigurator.configure(logFile);

    Logger log = Logger.getRootLogger();
    String fileAppenderName = ...
    FileAppender fa = (FileAppender)log.getAppender(fileAppenderName);
    fa.setFile(yourLogFile)
```

Comment: what about fileAppenderName ?

Comment: I'm assuming you still have a *log4j.xml* or *log4j.properties* file where you configure all your appenders and you only want to alter the file where the log is put in execution time. So, if you are using a *log4j.xml* file, the appender name would be whatever you put in your appender configuration. For instance:

    <appender name="yourAppenderName" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    ...
    </appender>